# What do the numbers in square brackets that come after the letters mean? AFRH15[3:0]. STM32 registers

Tags: stm32, register

The images show STM32 registers.
What do the numbers [1:0] after the name mean?
MODER15[1:0]
AFRH15[3:0]
The first digit is the number of bits if you start counting from zero.
What does the second number after the colon mean?

If this means that the countdown starts from zero, then why do I need such strange information?
The countdown always starts from zero in the registers.
This means AFRH15[3:0]
The countdown starts from zero and there are only 4 bits?

(Below diagram taken from [user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).)

[image]

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add a source reference for the diagram it shows, as parts shown of other documents must be credited with a reference. For example, adding a link to the document on the manufacturer's website would be ideal. Otherwise your question may get a friendly but firm visit from a moderator :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, for AFRH1 there are 4 bits numbered 3 to 0, and they occupy bits 31..28 of the 32-bit register.

It's nothing complicated.

Comment: How to decode it?
Bits 31 30 COUNT[4:3]
The countdown starts at 30.
The maximum number of bits here is 5.
Then this Bits 31 30 should be written as
COUNT[4:30] and not COUNT[4:3] ?

Comment: [3:0] is just a popular notation for a 4-bit vector with bits numbered 3 to 0. If you concatenate 8 of them you can fill up the 32  bits. If you needed to break out (say) AFRH1 you would use some language-dependent construct that would likely refer to [31:28] in the register.

Answer (score 0):

It's that bitfield value's range, as high:low.

For example, `MODER15` is a 2-bit bitfield and carries bits 1 down to 0 of the MODER15 value.

This notation allows a register bitfield to hold part of a value or split that value into sections and scatter them into different register bitfields.

So for example, registers could carry all of 5-bit value `COUNT[4:0]` as:

```
  Bits 31 30 29    COUNT[4:2]
  Bits 15 14       COUNT[1:0]
```

Or only carry just bits 4:3 of 5-bit value `COUNT[4:0]`, with bits 2:0 inaccessible, as:

```
  Bits 31 30       COUNT[4:3]
```

So it's a pretty flexible notation.

(The below image is taken from your question's image.)

[image]

Comment: Very interesting but not clear
Here you write:
>For example, MODER15 is a 2-bit bitfield and carries bits 1 down to 0 of the MODER15 value.

But this Bits 15 14 COUNT[1:0] from your example does not fit this description.
15 is 5 bits, so it should be COUNT[4:x]
>and carries bits 1 down to 0 of the MODER15 value.
Bits 15 14 
Here, probably, values ​​​​from the number 14 are transferred?
And the maximum number of bits in the numbers 14 and 15 is 5.
Then following this instruction
>and carries bits 1 down to 0 of the MODER15 value.
get COUNT[4:14]
5 bits and counting starts from 14.